# How can I cleanly present well-formed names keys and values from JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to output some JSON to my user.  The format of that JSON can vary though, and the depth of the JSON can also vary.  It could be anywhere from 1-5 levels deep.

Some example JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Previous DNS Records",
    "value": [
      {
        "host": "***.co.uk",
        "class": "IN",
        "ttl": 3573,
        "type": "TXT",
        "txt": "ANY obsoletedSee draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any",
        "entries": [
          "ANY obsoleted",
          "See draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "New DNS Records",
    "value": [
      {
        "host": "***.co.uk",
        "class": "IN",
        "ttl": 3516,
        "type": "TXT",
        "txt": "ANY obsoletedSee draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any",
        "entries": [
          "ANY obsoleted",
          "See draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to loop through and display the keys and values in some sort of presentable way to my user, whether that's using a `<table>` or `<dl>`, with the key being the name and the value within.

However, because I don't know the depth of the JSON or whether the value is a string or JSON itself this is proving tricky.  That said, this is a pretty common use-case, so I'm wondering if there's a library or built-in JS method to help me out here that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Have a look at Vue.

Comment: I'm actually using Vue.  How would that help though?

Comment: _this is a pretty common use-case_ - Having data models with unknown model definitions, variable types, lengths and depths is not a common use case. You don't have a coding issue, you have a design issue.

Comment: It all depends on the final rendering you want to have. Maybe a simple JS library "JSON viewver" or "JSON formatter" will be enough.

If you have to format the data further, a template engine will be more useful (Handlebars.js for example). You will be able to transform the values of your objects into an HTML element and add them classes and the associated CSS.

https://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: can we see the example of how the thing would look like when there is different depth? usually you can just use recursion on each value to check if it is actually value or an object and then either output it as key value into html or do another wrapper and repeat the story

Comment: As Randy says, this is really a user interface design issue. What type of users will be viewing this data? If they are fairly technical then maybe a interactive tree [like this one](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) would suffice? Alternatively maybe there are *some* constraints you can place on the JSON that allow a simpler rendering of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my simple **JIterator IIFE** and play with each node. Has also BreadthFirst predefined.
But DepthFirst seems to fit better here:

```js
function demoPrint() {
  var it = new JIterator(DemoJSON());
  do {
    var el = it.Current();
    if (el.HasOwnKey()) {
      if(el.HasStringValue()) {
        console.log("Level " + it.Level + " | " + el.key + '\t' + el.value);
      } else {
        console.log("Level " + it.Level + " | " + el.key + " ⤦");
      }
    } else if (el.HasStringValue()) {
      console.log("Level " + it.Level + " | " + el.value);
    }
  } while (it.DepthFirst());
}
function DemoJSON() {
  return [
  {
    "name": "Previous DNS Records",
    "value": [
      {
        "host": "***.co.uk",
        "class": "IN",
        "ttl": 3573,
        "type": "TXT",
        "txt": "ANY obsoletedSee draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any",
        "entries": [
          "ANY obsoleted",
          "See draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "New DNS Records",
    "value": [
      {
        "host": "***.co.uk",
        "class": "IN",
        "ttl": 3516,
        "type": "TXT",
        "txt": "ANY obsoletedSee draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any",
        "entries": [
          "ANY obsoleted",
          "See draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }];
}

// https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Iterator_IIFE.js
'use strict';
var JNode = (function (jsNode) {

    function JNode(_parent, _pred, _key, _value) {
        this.parent = _parent;
        this.pred = _pred;
        this.node = null;
        this.next = null;
        this.key = _key;
        this.value = _value;
    }
    JNode.prototype.HasOwnKey = function () { return this.key && (typeof this.key != "number"); }
    JNode.prototype.HasStringValue = function () { return !(this.value instanceof Object); }

    return JNode;
})();

var JIterator = (function (json) {
    var root, current, maxLevel = -1;

    function JIterator(json, parent) {
        if (parent === undefined) parent = null;
        var pred = null, localCurrent;
        for (var child in json) {
            var obj = json[child] instanceof Object;
            if (json instanceof Array) child = parseInt(child); // non-associative array
            if (!root) root = localCurrent = new JNode(parent, null, child, json[child]);
            else {
                localCurrent = new JNode(parent, pred, child, obj ? ((json[child] instanceof Array) ? [] : {}) : json[child]);
            }
            if (pred) pred.next = localCurrent;
            if (parent && parent.node == null) parent.node = localCurrent;
            pred = localCurrent;
            if (obj) {
                var memPred = pred;
                JIterator(json[child], pred);
                pred = memPred;
            }
        }
        if (this) {
            current = root;
            this.Level = 0;
        }
    }

    JIterator.prototype.Current = function () { return current; }
    JIterator.prototype.SetCurrent = function (newCurrent) { current = newCurrent; }
    JIterator.prototype.Parent = function () {
        var retVal = current.parent;
        if (retVal == null) return false;
        this.Level--;
        return current = retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.Pred = function () {
        var retVal = current.pred;
        if (retVal == null) return false;
        return current = retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.Node = function () {
        var retVal = current.node;
        if (retVal == null) return false;
        this.Level++;
        return current = retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.Next = function () {
        var retVal = current.next;
        if (retVal == null) return false;
        return current = retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.Key = function () { return current.key; }
    JIterator.prototype.KeyDots = function () { return (typeof (current.key) == "number") ? "" : (current.key + ':'); }
    JIterator.prototype.Value = function () { return current.value; }
    JIterator.prototype.Reset = function () {
        current = root;
        this.Level = 0;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.RawPath = function () {
        var steps = [], level = current;
        do {
            if (level != null && level.value instanceof Object) {
                steps.push(level.key + (level.value instanceof Array ? "[]" : "{}"));
            } else {
                if (level != null) steps.push(level.key);
                else break;
            }
            level = level.parent;
        } while (level != null);
        var retVal = "";
        retVal = steps.reverse();
        return retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.Path = function () {
        var steps = [], level = current;
        do {
            if (level != null && level.value instanceof Object) {
                var size = 0;
                var items = level.node;
                if (typeof (level.key) == "number") steps.push('[' + level.key + ']');
                else {
                    while (items) {
                        size++;
                        items = items.next;
                    }
                    var type = (level.value instanceof Array ? "[]" : "{}");
                    var prev = steps[steps.length - 1];
                    if (prev && prev[0] == '[') {
                        var last = prev.length - 1;
                        if (prev[last] == ']') {
                            last--;
                            if (!isNaN(prev.substr(1, last))) {
                                steps.pop();
                                size += '.' + prev.substr(1, last);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    steps.push(level.key + type[0] + size + type[1]);
                }
            } else {
                if (level != null) {
                    if (typeof (level.key) == "number") steps.push('[' + level.key + ']');
                    else steps.push(level.key);
                }
                else break;
            }
            level = level.parent;
        } while (level != null);
        var retVal = "";
        retVal = steps.reverse();
        return retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.DepthFirst = function () {
        if (current == null) return 0; // exit sign
        if (current.node != null) {
            current = current.node;
            this.Level++;
            if (maxLevel < this.Level) maxLevel = this.Level;
            return 1; // moved down
        } else if (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
            return 2; // moved right
        } else {
            while (current != null) {
                if (current.next != null) {
                    current = current.next;
                    return 3; // returned up & moved next
                }
                this.Level--;
                current = current.parent;
            }
        }
        return 0; // exit sign
    }
    JIterator.prototype.BreadthFirst = function () {
        if (current == null) return 0; // exit sign
        if (current.next) {
            current = current.next;
            return 1; // moved right
        } else if (current.parent) {
            var level = this.Level, point = current;
            while (this.DepthFirst() && level != this.Level);
            if (current) return 2; // returned up & moved next
            do {
                this.Reset();
                level++;
                while (this.DepthFirst() && level != this.Level);
                if (current) return 3; // returned up & moved next
            } while (maxLevel >= level);
            return current != null ? 3 : 0;
        } else if (current.node) {
            current = current.node;
            return 3;
        } else if (current.pred) {
            while (current.pred) current = current.pred;
            while (current && !current.node) current = current.next;
            if (!current) return null;
            else return this.DepthFirst();
        }
    }
    JIterator.prototype.ReadArray = function () {
        var retVal = {};
        var item = current;
        do {
            if (item.value instanceof Object) {
                if (item.value.length == 0) retVal[item.key] = item.node;
                else retVal[item.key] = item;
            } else retVal[item.key] = item.value;
            item = item.next;
        } while (item != null);
        return retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.FindKey = function (key) {
        var pos = current;
        while (current && current.key != key) this.DepthFirst();
        if (current.key == key) {
            var retVal = current;
            current = pos;
            return retVal;
        } else {
            current = pos;
            return null;
        }
    }

    return JIterator;
})();

demoPrint();
```