# How to access nested json object via string value

Tags: arrays, json, object, nested

In a json response, there are multiple nested objects named "generic_equipment_name" and I need to confirm if there is one whose value is "Push-button start". How can I check for the presence of this "generic_equipment_name" as well as the value of its associated object "generic_equipment_value"? Not all responses will contain this object, and other objects not listed below may be included (response is dynamic) which is why I'm looking to check for it. Sample response:

```
"standard_generic_equipment": [
{
    "generic_equipment_category_group": "Interior",
    "generic_equipment_categories": [
        {
            "generic_equipment_category": "Air Conditioning",
            "generic_equipment": [
                {
                    "generic_equipment_name": "Air filtration",
                    "generic_equipment_values": [
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "429",
                            "generic_equipment_value": "active charcoal"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "generic_equipment_category": "Comfort Features",
            "generic_equipment": [
                {
                    "generic_equipment_name": "Armrests",
                    "generic_equipment_values": [
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "712",
                            "generic_equipment_value": "rear center folding with pass-thru"
                        },
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "1557",
                            "generic_equipment_value": "rear center with cupholders"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "generic_equipment_name": "Center console trim",
                    "generic_equipment_values": [
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "2865",
                            "generic_equipment_value": "leatherette"
                        },
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "558",
                            "generic_equipment_value": "wood"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "generic_equipment_category": "Convenience Features",
            "generic_equipment": [
                {
                    "generic_equipment_name": "Power steering",
                    "generic_equipment_values": [
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "862",
                            "generic_equipment_value": "variable/speed-proportional"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "generic_equipment_name": "Power windows",
                    "generic_equipment_values": [
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "1425",
                            "generic_equipment_value": "lockout button"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "generic_equipment_name": "Push-button start",
                    "generic_equipment_values": [
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "1665",
                            "generic_equipment_value": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "generic_equipment_name": "Reading lights",
                    "generic_equipment_values": [
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "850",
                            "generic_equipment_value": "front"
                        },
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "1700",
                            "generic_equipment_value": "rear"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "generic_equipment_name": "Rearview mirror",
                    "generic_equipment_values": [
                        {
                            "generic_equipment_id": "2154",
                            "generic_equipment_value": "auto-dimming"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: What is the language or tool you are trying to use to solve the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279135/how-can-i-cleanly-present-well-formed-names-keys-and-values-from-json-in-javascr/57389772#57389772

In case JS, I made 2 iterator IIFEs, which may help...