# Is there a way to do something similar to JSON.parse(str, reviver), but on an object that already exists?

Tags: javascript, json

When you call `JSON.parse(str, reviver)`, the `reviver` function gets called for every key value pair, starting at the most nested, allowing you to transform say all numbers to date objects, etc.

Is there a easy way to do this on an object that already exists, that isn't just a recursive function called on all keys of the current object?

I also understand I could use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj),reviver)`, but that feels like it could cause more problems than just using recursion.

Comment: there are plenty of ways to map through objects - can you show your `reviver` code?

Comment: What about general iterator like example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279135/how-can-i-cleanly-present-well-formed-names-keys-and-values-from-json-in-javascr/57389772#57389772 or JNode on my https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/tree/master/HTM_HTA